# Create associative array on Jqueries each loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I try to create a new object with jquery each but only the last element of my looped is getting added to my object

```
var selectArray ={}; 
    $.each(response, function( i, x ){
          selectArray['id'] = x.id;
          selectArray['text'] = x.name;                            
    });
 console.log(selectArray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array and push a new object containing the keys and values:

```
var selectArray = []; 
$.each(response, function( i, x ){
      selectArray.push({"id":x.id, "name":x.name})                           
});
console.log(selectArray);
```

Comment: Objects don't have a `push` method. Arrays do, though.

Comment: I don't think the user wants to just make a clone of the input array (which this effectively does, unless the goal is to create objects leaving out all properties other than `id` and `name`). "Associative" suggests doing a map of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

You've said "associative array" (that's not a term used with JavaScript; they're just "objects"), so I'm guessing you want to create an object where `selectArray['some id']` will give you `name`:

```
var selectArray = {}; 
$.each(response, function( i, x ){
    selectArray[x.id] = x.name;
});
console.log(selectArray);
```

So for instance, if your `response` contained three items (id "tjc" => name "T.J. Crowder", id "joeblow" => name "Joe Blow", and id "bozscaggs" => name "Boz Scaggs"), you'd end up with an object that looked like this:

```
{
    "tjc":       "T.J. Crowder",
    "joeblow":   "Joe Blow",
    "bozscaggs": "Boz Scaggs"
}
```

and

```
selectArray['tjc']
```

...would give you `"T.J. Crowder"`.

Complete Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/xefikoto/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Creating a lookup object</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Look in the console</p>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var response = [
        {id: "tjc", name: "T.J. Crowder"},
        {id: "joeblow", name: "Joe Blow"},
        {id: "bozscaggs", name: "Boz Scaggs"}
      ];
      var selectArray = {}; 
      $.each(response, function( i, x ){
        selectArray[x.id] = x.name;
      });
      console.log(selectArray);
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```